# Procesar cadena de caracter con ciclo while

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Alguien podria explicarme la logica de este ejercicio no me queda muy claro

Se trata de ingresar un email y verificar si lleva el caracter "@"

```
mail=input("Ingrese un email")
cantidad=0
x=0

while x<len(mail): #<-Esto no me queda claro lo que hace
   if mail[x]=='@'
      cantidad=cantidad+1 #Aqui es donde se guarda en la variable cantidad el caracter '@" ?
   x=x+1 #porque se vuelve a iniciar el bucle?

if cantidad==1: # Porque cantidad se compara a 1?
     print("Contiene solo un caracter @ el mail introducido")
else:
     print("Incorrecto")
```

Gracias por su tiempo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que el algoritmo busca es contar el número de caracteres "@" que hay en una cadena. Para ello se usa un bucle `while`, que **itera (repitiendo un bloque de código) mientras su condición de control (la cual le sigue cuando se declara) es evaluada como verdadera.**

Lo que queremos por tanto es iterar sobre los caracteres de la cadena uno a uno, ver si el carácter es una "@" (`if mail[x]=='@'`) y en caso afirmativo incrementar el contador de "@" en uno (`cantidad=cantidad+1`).

La variable `x` representa el índice que tiene el carácter en la cadena, los indices en Python empiezan en 0 y queremos iterar desde el primer carácter (índice 0) hasta el último (cuyo índice es la longitud de la cadena menos 1, al haber empezado a contar con 0). Por eso la condición del `while` es:

```
x<len(mail)
```

El built-in [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) retorna la longitud o número de items de un iterable, en este caso retorna el número de caracteres de la la cadena `mail`.

Por lo tanto `x` se inicializa a 0 antes del `while` (para empezar por el primer carácter) y en cada iteración se incrementa en 1 para pasar al siguiente carácter, eso es lo que hace `x=x+1`, esto no inicializa el ciclo de nuevo, solo incrementa la variable de control del mismo. `while x<len(mail)` se "traduce" por tanto en "*mientras x sea menor que la logitud de mail*".

Si no incrementamos `x` dentro del ciclo  la condición `x>len(mail)` siempre sería cierta dado que `x` sería siempre 0 (valor inicial) y tendríamos un ciclo infinito (a no ser que `mail` fuera una cadena vacía).

Para entender como se van obteniendo los caracteres veamos un ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> cad = "Hola"
> >>> len(cad)     # Longitud de la cadena, 4 caracteres
> 4
> >>> cad[0]       # Carácter en posición 0
> 'H'
> >>> cad[1]       # Carácter en posición 1
> 'o'
> >>> cad[2]       # Carácter en posición 2
> 'l'
> >>> cad[3]       # Carácter en posición 3
> 'a'
>
> >>> cad = "Hola"
> >>> indice = 0
> >>> while indice < len(cad):
>         print("indice: {} - cad[indice]: {}".format(indice, cad[indice]))
>         indice += 1
>
>
> indice: 0 - cad[indice]: H
> indice: 1 - cad[indice]: o
> indice: 2 - cad[indice]: l
> indice: 3 - cad[indice]: a
> ```

La comparación es `if cantidad==1:` porque queremos validar que la cadena **solo contenga una @**, ni menos ni más, cualquier otra posibilidad es un email inválido.

Cabe destacar que esta es una muy mala forma de iterar sobre una cadena  en Python, es ineficiente y "feo". Python permite iterar sobre una cadena (o cualquier iterable cuando no tengamos pensado modificar su longitud mientras iteramos sobre el) con un `for in`, mucho más eficiente y legible que un `while` e indexado. Podemos hacer algo similar pero más eficiente y "pitónico" por tanto:

```
contador = 0

for caracter in mail:
    if caracter == "@":
        contador += 1
```

O usar un generador con `sum`:

```
contador = sum(caracter == "@" for caracter in mail)
```

O directamente usar `str.count` que sería lo lógico:

```
contador = mail.count("@")
```

Comment: Bien explicado, gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

vamos a analizar y explicar tu codigo linea por linea

1.- ingresar el correo electronico desde la linea de comando
2.- establecer la bandera "cantidad" = 0
3.- establecer la bandera "x" = 0;
4.- mientras el valor de "x" sea menor que la longitud de caracteres del correo repetir ,

> esta linea es un bloque de codigo que cuando llegue al final regresara aqu y repitira la condicion anterior, si la condicion es valida el bloque de codigo se repetira, si no es validad saltara hasta el final del bloque

5.-si mail[x] es igual a "@" entonces

> mail es una cadena o arreglo de caracteres, para acceder a una posicion del arreglo o la cadena en especifico puedes utilizar los corchetes [], como x inicial es = 0, entonces se analizara la primer posicion del arreglo

6.- cantidad = cantidad + 1,   finaliza condicion if
7.- x=x+, Finaliza ciclo while

Answer (score -2):

```
email = 'user@correo.com'

validate = email.split('@')
if(len(validate) == 2):
    print('Contiene solo un caracter @ el mail introducido')
else:
    print("Incorrecto")
```

la variable `email` contiene un string con el correo y con metodo `str.split()`, `email.split('@')` rompe la cadena de string donde halla un `'@'` y retorna una lista con los string divididos en este caso `['user', 'correo.com']` y finalmente validamos, `si` la lista tiene longitud igual a 2 eso quiere decir que el correo solo tiene una @ y es un email correcto, en caso contrario `else` es si el correo no tiene ninguna @ o tiene mas de una @

Comment: Por favor, mira [answer] y tambien haz el [tour]. Gracias por la respuesta, pero las mismas no deben ser solo codigo, deben ser bien completas explicando la solucion al problema.

Comment: bueno es otra forma de realizarlo @gbianchi

Comment: Agrega por favor una explicación de lo que realiza el código, es importante.